# How can I parse an RSS feed using something other than PHP?

Tags: javascript, json, rss

I want to parse the RSS feed found here: http://blog.everybodyedits.com/feed/

The problem is, I can't parse it using PHP (the host we use doesn't allow it).  I have seen many others that use jQuery and AJAX, but they all show an entire list of blog posts. I would like to only show one post (only the title and contents, not the comments, and author, and date and extra stuff).

Some of the jQuery scripts I have tried don't bring up anything.

If there are easier/simpler ways to doing this, I'm open ears.

I would like to avoid third party sites if I can.

Comment: there's nothing magical about php. RSS is just an XML document, and any language that can handle xml (or even just text) could handle RSS.

Comment: Are you saying that when you do say, for ease of my question, a file_get_contents($url) you are not able to get the XML?

Comment: Yes, for some reason it doesn't show anything.  However, PHP does.

This PHP code works great:
$feed = file_get_contents('http://blog.everybodyedits.com/feed/');
$rss = simplexml_load_string($feed); // PHPify it with black magic
$title = $rss->channel->item->title."<br />\n"; // Get the title
$rawpost = $rss->channel->item->children('content', true)->encoded."\n";
$comments = strrpos($rawpost, '<a rel="nofollow"');
$post = substr($rawpost, 0, $comments);
echo "<h1>".$title."</h1>\n";
echo $post."\n";

Comment: Is *simplexml* installed? Maybe you should use *DOMDocument* if available. In my opinion a far better XML parser than simplexml

Comment: I am able to parse this xml with no problem. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, it doesn't show anything at all. The rest of the page I'm using it on loads fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create the file locally and then parse it. That way you can access it with either PHP or JavaScript later. Start with something like this:

```
<?php 
$file = "/var/www/path_to_your/file.xml";
$data = file_get_contents("http://blog.everybodyedits.com/feed/");

file_put_contents($file, $data);

$local_file_data = simplexml_load_file($file);
//var_dump($local_file_data);
//To parse
foreach ($local_file_data as $key => $value) {
    echo $value->title;
}
```

Tail your logs to see what your error is if any. You might have a permissions issue with creating you file or be parsing the file incorrectly -  which might be why you do not see anything.

If you want to parse your xml using JQuery, have a look at [this documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for examples.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
    url: "http://your_server.com/file.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
       console.log(xml);
    }
});
```

**Note**:
To set up PHP error logging type in you commandline: `php -i | more` and that will tell you where your php.ini files are. Then make a copy and edit it and see [this documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php).

Comment: I can't use any PHP.  This is all being hosted on Yahoo Games and they don't allow php scripts.

Comment: What about the JQuery example that is in my answer?

Comment: I don't understand your first example, but the second example gives me two errors.

Both say: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Umm I actually get a status 200 indicating that they will not let you pull the XML with just java script. I recommend creating a PHP script on your server, pull the data onto the server and then hitting your own server to get the data. You can pull their data onto your server. I did it. Then point your ajax call to your own server.

Comment: Um. Let me just clarify here...
use PHP to get the data onto my server, then use ajax to get it from my server?

Comment: Your goal is to parse right? If they will not let you do it directly, then you have to think out-side the box and get the data via PHP or Python etc on your server. So yes.

Comment: Okay, I will mess around with this a little bit later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to what I was looking for... kinda.  It relies on a third party site, but it doesn't use PHP and it's easily changeable.

I decided to go with [Google's Feed Api](https://developers.google.com/feed/).

The code is very easy to change, and it's not likely that Google's servers ever go down so I'm not too worried. I don't have problems loading anything either.